# date is changing when writing dataframe to csv

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I have a dataframe which has dates like

```
    Date of Birth
0   28041977
1   12071993
2   26061988
3   27051984
4   03091983
```

when I am writing it to csv the last row at index 4 is changing

```
    Date of Birth
0   28041977
1   12071993
2   26061988
3   27051984
4   3091983
```

'01-01-78 12:00:00.000000000 AM'

I tried

```
df['Date of Birth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date of Birth'],format='%d%m%Y')
df['Date of Birth'] = df['Date of Birth'].dt.strftime('%d%m%Y')
df.to_csv('TU_third_batch_sample.csv',index=False,date_format='%d%m%Y',
          quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC,quotechar='"',escapechar='\\',formatters ={'Date of Birth':format_dob})
```

but nothing is working I wanted date column to remain as it is

```
    Date of Birth
0   28041977
1   12071993
2   26061988
3   27051984
4   03091983
```

Comment: can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Why are you using `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`?

Comment: **To question text add as text the following**. 1) I am assuming you are using Pandas, so what version?  2) Where is `formatters =` coming from? I don't see that here [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).